# Javascript return function in another function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, return

I have a javascript which is like this

```
function one (var1, var2){
    var var3= var1+var2;
    return var3;
}

function two( var4, var5){
    var var6=var4*var5;
    return var6;
}

function three(var7, var8){
    var9=var7/var8;
    return var9;
}

var first = one(2, 4);

var second= two(first, 8);

var third= three(second, 9);
```

I want all the function to be separate because they each are like module which would handle different operations. So I do not want to use callback, I have tried

```
$.ajax(first = one(2,4))
.then({second=two(first, 8)})
.then(three(second,9))
```

I have also tried this

```
$.ajax()
.then(function(first=one(2,4){
    return first;
})
.then(function(second=two(first,4){
    return second;
})
```

I have also tried this

```
$.ajax({
    first:one(2,4),
    second:two(first,4),
    third:three(second,9),
})
.then(function(first=one(2,4){
    return first;
})
.then(function(second=two(first,4){
    return second;
})
```

this may sound funny but I even tried

```
var third= three(two(one(2, 4), 8), 9);
```

amongst many others.
All of them show operation takes place with the first function and other functions but the it does not give me result from previous function

---

**This is an update to the above.
Modification**

**I do not want to use promise in the other functions as some other functions would also call those functions and they would not be expecting a promise but a valid data**

```
function modifyData(details){
    for(var x=0 ;x<array.length;x++){
        //this would do a massive loop which would
        //return a json string that would be 
    }
 }


 function tableFunction(url, tableNameVar){
    //json fields
 var details=[];
 details[0] = 'name'; 
 details[1] = 'sex'; 
 details[2] = 'eye_color'; 
 details[3] = 'height'; 
 details[4] = 'body_built'; 
        var jsonData='';
        var main = "";
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $('#'+tableNameVar+'').dataTable({
            destroy: true,
            data: JSON.parse(extraFunctionProcess(modifyData(details),details)),
            columns:[
                     {title: "Name", data:"name"} ,
                     {title: "Gender", data:"sex"} ,
                     {title: "Eye color", data:"eye_color"} ,
                     {title: "Height", data:"height"} ,
                     {title: "Body built", data:"body_built"} 
            ]
        });
    });
}
```

I want to process the data and put it inside the table. The extraFunctionProcess has worked if the data is passed 
straight into the data field without putting it inside the modifyData function.
 which is instead of the above it is

```
data: JSON.parse(extraFunctionProcess(fullData,details))
```

This has worked but due to the modification which I have done, it has brought up an error in my browser console which is 
undefined inside the extraFunctionProcess.

I just shortened the code into I put online now.

Comment: This question is very unclear. The first and last code blocks should all work. It's unclear what you expect the `$.ajax` calls to do, since you're not passing proper options to `$.ajax`.

Comment: Both the first and last way give `5.33333333333333`, exactly what's expected. What are you asking? What are you trying to accomplish? I cannot make heads or tails of this question. Please also check http://xyproblem.info/ just in case.

Comment: As @ChrisG said I have the same result. And don't get what are you expecting. Also I noticed you are using callbacks(not using) incorrectly. You have to pass function name to a function where you are using ajax then call it when completes.

Comment: Just in case this is about multiple chained API calls, you can indeed chain $.ajax() calls. You cannot chain your functions though because they aren't returning Promises. Take a step back and tell us what your actual goal is, don't ask about a perceived solution that might be completely off track.

Comment: `$.ajax` has not anything to do with your problem. You are not using callbacks, hence Promise has also anything to with it. Also, you are not using async code.

Comment: Here's your code, fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/yo2nbwh4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have actually found a solution to the problem. The modifyData function was the one with the problem. The return was inside another function.
Intead of the following

```
function modifyData(details){
    for(var x=0 ;x<array.length;x++){
        //this would do a massive loop which would
        //return a json string that would be inside a function
    }
 }


function modifyData(details){
    for(var x=0 ;x<array.length;x++){
         return functionName(callback to be done);
        //this would do a massive loop which would
        //return a json string that would be 
    }
 }
```